# Jquery select not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div -

```
<div id="billTypeDropDown" class="form-group dropdown"></div>
```

I am using jquery to set a select element inside this div

```
$('#billTypeDropDown').html(getDropDown('billtype'));
```

After this my select looks like this -
[image]

Now, In my another jquery flow, I am using this code -

```
$('#billTypeDropDown select option[value="Select One"]').prop('selected', true); //this is called after preparing the page
$('#billTypeDropDown').find('select').find('option').filter(function(){
                return $(this).prop('id') == $candidate.emp_type_c;
            }).prop('selected', true); //this is called when I have data on the page
```

But this simple second statement which is supposed to set the value from $candidate.emp_type_c is not setting the selected value in my dropdown select.

I tried all these, but none of these work -

```
$('#billTypeDropDown select option[id='+$candidate.emp_type_c+']').attr('selected', 'selected');

$('#billTypeDropDown').find('select').find('option').each(function(){
                if($(this).prop('id') == $candidate.emp_type_c){
                    $(this).prop('selected', true);
                }
            });

$('#billTypeDropDown').find('select').find('option').filter(function(){
                return $(this).prop('id') == $candidate.emp_type_c;
            }).prop('selected', true);
```

Can you please point out the error?

PS -I have another dropdown, and this code work fine for that -

```
$('#visaDropDown select option').filter(function(){
            return $(this).prop('id') == $candidate.visa_type_c;
        }).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, IDs cannot have spaces... and why are you using the ID for selection rather than the value?

Comment: Because that is what has been stored in the DB. I am working on an existing system. And except for "Select One" none of the options have spaces in the ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the value of the select itself:

```
$('#billTypeDropDown select').val('Select One');
```

Comment: The value that I am getting in $candidate.emp_type_c is the id of options.

Comment: Then just get the value stored at that id and use that to set the value: `$('#billTypeDropDown select').val($('#'+selectedId).val())`

Comment: :) let me try that.

Comment: Still no luck. Funny thing is, I have another dropdown, and this code is working fine for that. I have updated the question.

Comment: It appears that you are using invalid `id` attributes (for example `1099` - id properties (non HTML5) must start with a letter and not contain spaces). The example I posted should be working for you: https://jsfiddle.net/2ycozdhv/

Comment: Then what about other options, W2 and corptocorp, they start with a letter and dont have spaces. Why are they not getting selected? I tried this - $candidate.emp_type_c = 'corptocorp';
   $('#billTypeDropDown select').val($('#'+$candidate.emp_type_c).val()); its still not working.

Comment: Are you sure that is being executed *after* `$('#billTypeDropDown').html(getDropDown('billtype'));`?

Comment: 100%. I used inspect element to $('#billTypeDropDownselect option'), and I am getting the option elements.

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing a reproducible example, please create a fiddle demonstrating the problem and I can try to help more.

Comment: Sure. I will do that.

Comment: Hi @Rob M. did you find anything? Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: I figured this one out. I had another piece of code called after that was setting it back to 'Select One'. Sorry about all the fuss. It was a complicated flow called on a hidden checkbox check status. I know messed up it is. I fixed it. Thanks a lot btw.